# What is the condition that allows a triangle to be enclosed between two homothetic hexagons?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

Let us suppose, as on the figure, that I have a (given) hexagon $DEFIHG$. Then, I build the hexagon $KLMNOP$, which is homothetic of ratio $\alpha$ of the first one ($\alpha$ is a parameter). That is, the outer hexagon is nothing more than the inner "scaled" by a factor $\alpha$.

Remark that each hexagon has three couples of sides parallel, as suggested on the figure. It is an assumption.

I am looking for a criterion such as $\alpha \geq ...$ for which there exists a triangle enclosed between the two hexagons, as the green triangle. By this, I mean, a triangle whose vertices are inside the outer hexagon and the edges do not cross the inner hexagon.

I would also be interested by the conditions leading to two different triangles

Thanks[image: eo]

Comment: Your hexagon has parallel opposite sides: is that a requested condition?

Comment: OK, anyway my solution is valid for ANY hexagon.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a hexagon $ABCDEF$ (as in diagram below) and want to construct a hexagon homothetic to it, containing triangle $HIJ$, which is obtained by producing sides $BC$, $DE$, $FA$.

The smaller of such hexagons will have three sides passing through $H$, $I$, $J$ and parallel to $EF$, $CD$, $AB$ respectively, lying then on triangle $NOP$ in diagram below. But triangle $NOP$ is homothetic to triangle $KLM$, obtained by producing sides $AB$, $CD$, $EF$ of the original hexagon. The center of homothety is $Q$, intersection of lines $KN$, $LO$ and $MP$ and the homothety ratio is
$$
\alpha={QN\over QK}={QO\over QL}={QP\over QM}.
$$

This homothety carries hexagon $ABCDEF$ to the requested minimal hexagon.

[image]

Comment: You write "The smaller of such hexagons will have three sides passing through H, I, J and parallel to EF, CD, AB respectively". Why couldn't it be the one passing by K, L, M and parallel to ED, CB, AF?

Comment: I did the construction for triangle $HIJ$, but of course it can be repeated for triangle $KLM$. You can do both and choose the one with smaller $\alpha$, if your goal is that of finding a lower bound on $\alpha$.

Comment: And wouldn't it possible that the triangle that leads to the "closest" (i.e. smallest $\alpha$) outer hexagon does not contain the whole segments FA, ED; BC but only one point per edge (for example only A, C, E). In other words, how do you "prove" that "The smaller of such hexagons will have three sides passing through H, I, J and parallel to EF, CD, AB respectively" ?

Comment: Yes, it could be possible in principle.